# Change Bg Image For all UIView

Tags: iphone

I have a project and I want to provide a feature to the user that allows them to change the background settings.  I would like that change to carry through on all UI screens.  What is the most efficient way of accomplishing this?

Right now I am able to keep the back ground detail in NSUserDefault.  When loading the view I check getBG() and apply that background in viewDidLoad().  However, I don't think this is the most efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

Make a class `YourView` in which you implement this behavior in the way that you like. It should inherit from `UIView`.

Then, change all your other classes from inheriting from `UIView` to inheriting from `YourView` instead.

(At least, I believe that you should be able to do what you want that way. If not, I just don't understand you correctly...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSNotification`.

When user changes the background image to one of his choice, then 
**post a notification**
& **add observer**, to change the background, where u have set the background image.